# Recovery lifestyle such as training scheduling and dieting for gluten-intolerant endurance runner?

Tags: diet, recovery, endurance, half-marathon, paleo-diet

Gluten-intolerance has surprises such as supplements with gluten, non-gluten products with gluten-contamination and non-absorption of necessary building products such as proteins and vitamins to the body. If hemoglobin going down during recovery due to stomach things, it can seriously affect running times and stamina.

*How should a gluten-intorelant endurance athlete design recovery lifestyle such as dieting and training schedule?*

**Perhaps related questions**

> 1. How should a gluten-intolerant design pre-workout diet?
> 2. How should a gluten-intolerant design intra-workout such as supplements during pumping?
> 3. How should a gluten intolerant athelete design training and diet during intestine recovery phase? (Amount of calories/vitamins/protein
>      up, detox training, more rest not to stress liver and other detox
>      organs?)
> 4. In general, which training schedules and resting schedules are most appropriate for the recovery time?
> 5. How should a gluten-intorelant design lifestyle during stomach-recovery when body mass going down and hemoglobins going down during intestine-recovery?
> 6. More general question about gluten-intolerant dieting in [How should a gluten intolerant plan diet?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4441/how-should-a-gluten-intolerant-plan-diet)
> 7. Cooking related question about [Surprising foods with gluten or gluten contamination?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/65561/surprising-foods-with-gluten-or-gluten-contamination)

Comment: Hrm. Not sure where you got the other 7 questions, but I wouldn't include them as it for sure makes the question way too broad. Not sure that even the basic question isn't too broad, but it stands a much better chance of getting answered. Also, can you specify what you mean by recovery? Normal workout recovery, or recovery from an episode of some sort?

Comment: Have you been diagnosed with celiac disease?